# Unsure how to go about static method

Tags: java, object, methods, static

Hi I'm a bit confused about how to go about the following method

Method  Description (JavaDoc Specification)

```
isOlder(objectp)
```

Yields: "p is not null and this Rhino is older than p".

```
isOlder(object p, object q)
```

Yields: "p and q are not null and p is older than q".
Make this function static and write it using the previous `isOlder(Rhino)` as a helper method.

I wrote the code for the first `isOlder(object p)`. I am unsure how to test out the second `isOlder(object p, object q)`

when I create a j unit test for it. It says `isOlder(object p, object q)` does not appear in the main class. Its a boolean expression but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Any help is appreaciated!

Comment: Looks like a homework problem..

Comment: Add the relevant code.

Comment: Did you actually write isOlder(Rhino, Rhino) method or not?

Comment: The explanation was much simpler than I expected in terms of outcome. I received help from a colleague. I apologize that the question wasn't more concrete

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public class Rhino {
   //...

   public boolean isOlder(Rhino r) {
      // compare this with r
      //...
   }

   public static boolean isOlder(Rhino p, Rhino q) {
      return p.isOlder(q);
   }
}
```

And you can test this static method by prefixing the method by the classname, e.g.

```
Rhino p = new ...
Rhino q = new ...
assertTrue(Rhino.isOlder(p, q));
```

Comment: Mere spoonfeeding is not an answer.

Comment: @EJP, I agree with your comment, but isn't it a bit hard for the downvote ?